# why we need accessor in autoimplemented property in c#?

Tags: c#

I have some doubts on the auto-implemented property. Why do we first get, and then set the value?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: If you have a Set without a Get the property wouldn't be very useful outside of the containing class.

Comment: You don't have to "Get" first before setting?!

Comment: what is the real need of this accessor.can you please explain

Comment: Post some code so we know what it is you have a query about.

Answer (score 1):

What you've have posted is not an auto property.

Below is an example class that contains 1 auto property and a custom property similar to what you have done.

```
public class MyPropertyClass
{
    public MyPropertyClass(bool affectLogic)
    {
        _affectLogic = affectLogic;
    }
    private readonly bool _affectLogic;

    public string MyAutoProperty { get; set; }

    private string _myPropertyWithLogic;
    public string MyPropertyWithLogic
    {
        get
        {
            if (_affectLogic)
                _myPropertyWithLogic = "Some value";

            return _myPropertyWithLogic;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_affectLogic)
            {
                _myPropertyWithLogic = "Some value";
            }
            else
            {
                _myPropertyWithLogic = value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The autoproperty "MyAutoProperty" provides a mechanism for simply getting and setting property values.

What you have posted in a standard property that allows you to perhaps manipulate or return the property value based upon certain conditions. In your post you are checking to see if the value posted in is null before setting.

If you do not need to access the property outside of the class then you do not need to have the get method. If you remove the get then you are creating a "WriteOnly" property which is bad practice.

Create a public method on the class that accepts the "Alert" value. If you dont need to access the property outside of the class then dont create a property at all.

```
public void SetMyProperty(string value)
{
     _myPropertyWithLogic = value;
}
```